# detect when Application.Current.RootVisual is set (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, app-startup

Assume I am making an assembly (WindowsPhoneClassLibrary or PortableClassLibrary) for a Windows Phone Application (Silverlight).

Is there a way for me to automatically detect/register/subscribe for the moment where `Application.Current.RootVisual` will be not null?

My current (not working because of Exception) approach is in the idea of:

```
var rootVisualTask = new TaskCompletionSource<UIElement>();
var application = Application.Current;
TaskEx.Run(() =>
{
    while (application.RootVisual == null)
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    rootVisualTask.TrySetResult(application.RootVisual);
});
var rootVisual = await rootVisualTask.Task;
```

### Edit

Answer to McGarnagle to explain how my assembly gets usually initialized.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
static readonly PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
}
void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    RootVisual = RootFrame;
    RootFrame.Navigated -= RootFrame_Navigated;
}
void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    MyPlugin.Start();
}
void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPlugin.Start();
}
```

Things happen in this order:

1. `Application.Startup` (unused)
2. `Application.Launching` (plugin starts)
3. `RootFrame.Navigated` (RootVisual is set, but RootFrame is private)

I could require a `MyPlugin.HeyRootVisualIsSetAndNowYouCanUseIt()` manually inserted after `RootVisual = ...` but I was trying to avoid that.

### Edit

Unlike Obj-C, [KVO is not implementable on Fields/Properties you don't own](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2009/08/knkvc-implementing-key-value-coding-and-key-value-observing-in-c-net/). Which means probably nobody is going to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for hours, I found this working:

```
var dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
var application = Application.Current;
UIElement rootVisual = null;
while (rootVisual == null)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UIElement>();
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(application.RootVisual));
    rootVisual = await taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

The `Thread.Sleep(1);` from the loop of my question is replaced with a call to `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to avoid Exception being thrown.